# Printing the tree path

Tags: python

I am learning python as one my project requirements is to print a binary tree.

I am trying out my code to print the tree path. 
It just stops at root node.
I am trying to find where I messed up.

> Tree:
>
> ```
>      A
>     / \
>    B   C
>   /   / \
>  D   E   F
> ```

The output I want is:

ABD

ACE

ACF

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.children = []
        self.val = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None


r = Node('A')
r.left = Node('B')
r.right = Node('C')
r.left.left = Node('D')
r.right.right = Node('E')
```

The above should be r.right.left = Node('E)
    r.right.right = Node('F')

```
def binaryTreePaths(root):
        results = []
        c = []
        binary_tree_paths(root, c, results)
        return results

def binary_tree_paths(root, cand, res):
    if root is None:
        return
    else:
        cand.append(str(root.val)+" ")
        if root.left is None and root.right is None:
            p = ''.join(map(str, cand))
            res.append(p)
        binary_tree_paths(root.left, cand, res)
        binary_tree_paths(root.right, cand, res)
        cand.pop()

print binaryTreePaths(r)
```

Comment: If it is binary tree, you should have left and right branches not a `children` array.

Comment: @ozgur - You are absolutely right. I messed up my code when initialized the tree.

Comment: @ozgur. I fixed the code. Still it prints only ['A B D ', 'A C F ']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have `r.right.left = Node('E')`, instead of `r.right.right = Node('E')`

Comment: @pm - Just found it. Thanks for the help